# Show that $Cx^{-1}$ is a solution to the differential equation $dy/dx+y^2=0$ only when $C=1\vee C=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I solved the linear differential to get $\frac{1}{x - c}$ and have set them equal to one another.

Where I get $c \cdot \left( c - x + 1 \right)$ and I see that that $c$ and $c + 1$ are roots. I'm not sure if this is the right direction.

When searching the answer online I am giving this as a solution.

> Schow that for any constant $C$, $y = C \cdot x^{-1}$ is a solution of equation $\left( 2 \right)$:
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x} + y^{2} &= \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\left( C \cdot x^{-1} \right) + \left( C \cdot x^{-1} \right)^{2}\\
> &= -C \cdot x^{-2} + C^{2} \cdot x^{-2}\\
> &= \left( -C + C^{2} \right) \cdot x^{-2}\\
> &= C \cdot \left( -1 + C \right) \cdot x^{-2}\\
> \\
> &= 0 \quad \left( \text{if}\, C = 0 \vee C = 1 \right)
> \end{align*}
> $$

I understand that we can plug in to get $\left( c \cdot x^{-1} \right)^{2}$ but why is it $\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\left( c^{x} - 1 \right)$ why is it not $\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\left( c \cdot x^{-1} \right)$?

And in this solution an ln is introduced of which I have a hard time following.

> b)
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x} &= -y^{2}\\
> -\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{y^{2}} &= \operatorname{d}x\\
> \end{align*}
> $$
> Integrating we get
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{y} &= x + C\\
> y &= \frac{1}{x + C}\\
> \end{align*}
> $$
> here if $C = 0$, then $y = \frac{1}{x + 0} = \frac{1}{x} = x^{-1}$ and solution is
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{y} &= x + \ln\left( C \right)\\
> \implies y &= \frac{1}{x + \ln\left( C \right)}\\
> \end{align*}
> $$
> if $C = 1$, then $y = \frac{1}{x + 0} = \frac{1}{x} = x^{-1}$
> $$\quad$$
> hence $x^{-1}$ is a solution only when $C = 1 \vee C = 0$.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning (on your second track) is correct for $C = 1$, but your explanation for $C = 0$ is flawed in my opinion. Your integration constant is $C$, as you have chosen. You can't just claim in the second block of equations that it's also $\ln\left( c \right)$ because that would imply $\implies C = \ln\left( C \right) \implies C^{-W_{k}\left( -1 \right)}$ (where $W_{k}$ is the [Lambert W Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html)) which isn't the case here.

To solve this problem, I would have simply substituted $y = C \cdot x^{-1}$ for $y$ in the differential equation and solved for $C$, wich you tried in on your first track:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x} + y^{2} &= 0\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\left( C \cdot x^{-1} \right) + \left( C \cdot x^{-1} \right)^{2} &= 0\\
-C \cdot x^{-2} + C^{2} \cdot x^{-2} &= 0\\
\left( -C + C^{2} \right) \cdot x^{-2} &= 0 \tag{zero product theorem}\\
-C + C^{2} &= 0 \wedge \underbrace{x^{-2} = 0}_{\implies x = 0^{-1}\, \text{can't be true}}\\
\left( -C + C^{2} \right) \cdot x^{-2} &= 0\\
-C + C^{2} &= 0\\
\left( -C + C^{2} \right) \cdot x^{-2} &= 0\\
\left( -1 + C \right) \cdot C &= 0 \tag{zero product theorem}\\
\underbrace{-1 + C}_{C = 1} &= 0 \wedge C = 0\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Where does our dy go when we substitute in to get d/dx*(C*x^-1)?

Comment: @user312484 We replaced the $y$ in $\operatorname{d}y$ with $C \cdot x^{-1}$ (substitution: $y := C \cdot x^{-1}$): $\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x} \overbrace{=}^{y := C \cdot x^{-1}} \frac{\operatorname{d}\left( C \cdot x^{-1} \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} = \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x} \left( C \cdot x^{-1} \right)$

Comment: thank you so much.